# Does System.Data.Sqlite support Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I looked around, and it was not clear if you could use it in EF6. I've found a compatible version on a blog ([here](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/systemdatasqlite-on-entity-framework-6.html)) but I'd rather use the official one if possible. Is it compatible or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, no official support yet. (Hence my blog post.) It's forked from the official codebase though, so the quality is as good as the official version.

Comment: @Brice That's a shame :( Thank you though for taking the time to fork and writing an excellent blog post on how to set it up, though!

Comment: @Brice Ah sorry I had a small mistake, fixed now. Sorry for clogging up your inbox :/

Answer (score 1):

Official support for Entity Framework 6 has been added in version 1.0.91.0 :

> **1.0.91.0 - February 12, 2014**
>
> - Updated to SQLite 3.8.3.1.
> - Refresh all included SQLite core library documentation (e.g. SQL syntax).
> - **Add support for Entity Framework 6**.
> - etc.

[Full release notes](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki)